# jquery mobile validate plugin initialized too many times

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm trying to apply jquery validate plugin to a jquery mobile form
i'm using:
jquery 2.1.1
jquery mobile 1.4.2
jquery validation plugin 1.11.0

validation initialization is called on pagecreate event:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page2', function(evt) {
    xxx.addCase.init();
});
```

init function performs various action among which:

```
xxx.addCase.form.validator    = xxx.addCase.form.validate({
        ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized],[name=contactName]), :hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',
        focusInvalid: false,
        focusCleanup: true,
        onclick: false,
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        errorPlacement: xxx.addCase.validationErrorPlacement,
        success: xxx.addCase.validationSuccess,
        rules: {
            SerialNumber__c: 'required',
            ContactId      : 'required',
            SuppliedPhone  : { required: { depends: function(element) {
                if('' === xxx.addCase.email.val())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            } }, phone: true, maxlength: 40 },
            SuppliedEmail  : { required: { depends: function(element) {
                if('' === xxx.addCase.phone.val())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            } }, email: true, maxlength: 80 },
            Subject        : { required: true, maxlength: 255 },
            Description    : { required: false, maxlength: 32000 },
            contactName    : { maxlength: 121 }
        },
        messages: {
            SuppliedPhone  : { required: addCaseFormTranslation.validate.custom.required },
            SuppliedEmail  : { required: addCaseFormTranslation.validate.custom.required }
        }, 
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //chiamata callback submit form
            xxx.addCase.form.submitter(form);
        }
    });
```

I noticed many different problems with this settings, so I made a little caveman debug putting console.logs in orginal jquery validate plugin:

```
validate: function( options ) {
    console.log('validating');
    ...
```

and

```
// constructor for validator
$.validator = function( options, form ) {
    console.log('constructor');
    console.log(options);
    console.log(form);
    this.settings = $.extend( true, {}, $.validator.defaults, options );
    this.currentForm = form;
    this.init();
};
```

this is what I obtain on firebug after page load and obviously what is causing problems (please consider it in relation to console.log calls):

validating
constructor
undefined

4 validating
constructor
Object { ignore=":hidden:not([class~=sele... .selectize-input input",  focusInvalid=false,  focusCleanup=true,  altri elementi...}

jquery validate is called 5 (five!) times the first of which without my settings, so I have no clue to understand why it beheaves so and how to call validator all at once.

Comment: `.validate()` is only called to ***initialize*** the plugin on your form, not for `"validating"` as your console log would lead one to believe.  How is it called the *first* time without your settings?  As long as your only call to `.validate()` contains the object literal containing your options, that's impossible.

Comment: You also need to explain which versions of everything.  The page init event for jQuery Mobile used to be called `pageinit` and now it's called `pagecreate`.

Comment: *"I noticed many different problems with this settings..."* **<<--** You're going to have to explain exactly what problems you're having as that's the issue we should be solving, rather than trying to figure out your troubleshooting methodology.  Your code formatting is also very strange... mixing 1TBS with Allman, yet not really following either one.

Comment: 1) my question is not a duplicate because the problem I point to has nothing to do with the marked question.
2)  I know that validate is used to initialize, infact my problem is that it is called five times!!!!! and only one time with my options.

Comment: 3) ok for versioning

4) I clearly pointed out which is my problem: plugin initialization is called five times, one time with my settings and four times with undefined options, this obviously causes problems like double error messages but these are just symptoms, I pointed out what are causing them and I was asking if anyone knows why there are 5 initialization calls.

Comment: When `.validate()` is called multiple times, only the first instance is used and all subsequent calls are ignored.  You're assuming that being called multiple times is causing the problems you never detailed, like seeing "double error messages".  I seriously doubt that.  Construct a MVCE and also a jsFiddle that duplicates the *actual problems* you're having.